# What is the $this->action variable in CakePHP?

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Hi fellows I need help in this line of code included in the Cakephp tutorial in the Simple Authentication and Authorization Application Section:

```
if (in_array($this->action, array('edit', 'delete'))){

}
```

I know what `the in_array()` function does but I don't know what the `$this->action` is all about and what does it contain, what does `$this->action` do in the first place?

can anyone please help me into this?

Comment: it contains the name of the action you are in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$this->action returns the name of your current action 
for example : 
your request = /posts/edit
in the controller :

```
class PostsController extends AppController{
   // ...
   public function beforeFilter(){
       parent::beforeFilter();
       debug($this->action); // = edit
   }
// ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `parent::beforeFilter();` statement for user validation.

For that in your controller

you have to use

```
function beforefilter()
{
     parent::beforeFilter();
}
```

This function will check user permission

Answer (score 0):

It should **$this->params['action']** instead of **$this->action**.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->action returns the action name of controller
```

in your case, in_array($this->action, array('edit', 'delete') checking for action name is edit or delete.

```
for debugging you can use 

pr($this->action);
```

Answer (score 0):

or better try

```
debug($this)
```

this will let you know about other class variables as well.